# SQL - Storing multiple records in a variable separated by commas

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, variables

I have two variables, 1 varchar named `cust_ref`, and 1 int named `associated_ids`. What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

You provide `cust_ref` with a value which will usually result in between 1+ rows being returned from the `Customer` table. I am concerned with gathering all `customer_id` records for that `cust_ref` and storing them in the `associated_ids` variable seperated by commars.

This is the SQL I have so far, and obviously is only loading one of the `customer_id` records into the variable. Based on this example I would like select `@associated_ids` to return the following `75458,77397,94955`

```
declare @cust_ref varchar(20) = 'ABGR55532'
declare @associated_ids int

select distinct @associated_ids = customer_id
from dbo.Customer
where cust_ref = @cust_ref

select @associated_ids

select *
from dbo.Customer
where cust_ref = @cust_ref
```

Here is the results from the above, as you can see there are actually 3 `associated_ids` that I need stored in the variable in this example but my command is capturing the largest, I want all 3 seperated by commars.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want anything to result in a comma separated string in SQL. If that is how it is presented in the UI, select out the rows and convert it in your DAL

Comment: I am creating a stored proc which will only need the cust_ref variable so that I can use IN (@associated_ids)

Comment: Also, I have had a look at the 'duplicates' and am struggling to make use of the FOR XML PATH syntax in my example, hence I would appreciate anyone providing the script for my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @cust_ref varchar(20) = 'ABGR55532' --from your code
DECLARE @result varchar(100)

set @result =
(SELECT distinct (customer_id + ' ')
FROM dbo.Customer 
where cust_ref = @cust_ref --from your code
ORDER BY (customer_id + ' ')
FOR XML PATH (''))

SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(@result),' ',',')
```

Comment: This is good but bringing back 754587739794955, which is correct just with no comma's

Comment: Please check the spaces. Only PATH('') doesnt have space, others have space in between.
What I'm getting at first is like - val1 val2 val3  - with a space at end.
Then I'm right trimming the last space, finally replacing spaces with commas. So, it should work!

Comment: Posted fixed query, please test that. Int columns were giving trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this ... obviously, some adjustment will be needed:

```
create table x (id varchar(50),num int)
insert into x (id,num) values ('75458','20')
insert into x (id,num) values ('77397','20')
insert into x (id,num) values ('94955','20')
```

and then,

```
create function GetList (@num as varchar(10)) 
returns varchar(100) 
as 
begin
  declare @List varchar(100) 
  select @List = COALESCE(@List + ', ', '') + id
  from x 
  where num = @num

  return @List

end
```

Then, use something like this to get the values:

```
select distinct num,dbo.GetList(num) from x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
DECLARE @cust_ref varchar(20) = 'ABGR55532' --from your code
DECLARE @result varchar(100)

set @result =
(SELECT distinct (cast(customer_id as varchar) + ' ')
FROM dbo.Customer 
where cust_ref = @cust_ref --from your code
ORDER BY (cast(customer_id as varchar) + ' ')
FOR XML PATH (''))

SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(@result),' ',',')
```